# MOSFET on-time calculation vs. measured

Tags: mosfet, switching, time-constant

I'm trying to compare the measured on-time of a fet compared to the theoretical on-time of the fet. My calcs are not aligning with the measured result. Here is my approach:

The fet is a [NIKO-SEM P8806BM](https://www.fet.discoveree.io/datasheet.php?file=niko-sem/p8806bm.pdf). There is a 3Mohm resistor in series with the gate of the fet. The device that drives this fet gate is the COUT pin on a [Ti BQ7721607](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq77216.pdf?ts=1641285491720). So the connection is: BQ7721607 COUT pin -> 3Mohm resistor -> P8806BM gate

The COUT pin has an active HIGH output drive of 6V, measured at 5.5V. The total gate charge of the P8806BM is 8.5nC.

To find the capacitance of the gate: C = Q/V = 8.5nC/5.5V = 1.54nF

The time constant Tau = R x C = 3Mohm x 1.54nF = 4.6ms

4(Tau) = 18.4ms.

So what is odd is my measured 4(Tau) is about 4.94ms, which is off from the calc's by a factor of about 3.7.

Is there something I am missing here? I've attached a scope shot of the fet gate, you can see the estimated 4(tau) is about 4.94ms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

QG for the FET includes gate..Source and gate..drain capacitance. If the drain V isn't changing, then the gate..drain capacitance doesn't have as much effect on the total QG and the C that you calculate.

gate..drain capacitance is very variable and depends on the drain voltage. If you put a pull-up R (any value -- 1k will work) on the drain, and bias that to ~ 30 V, your measurements will correlate better.

Comment: For this example, the FET drain is about 42.5V and the source is connected to ground.  The  42.5V drain is the top of a battery stack. This circuit will only fire the gate when the drain of the FET is a max of 42.5V. There are some caveats to that but for this example we'll just assume 42.5V is the source voltage. I still don't completely understand how best to correct my calculation, are you saying I should just use Qgs and not Qg? @jp314